# R Integration to Tableau simple correlation error

Tags: r, correlation, tableau-api

I am currently new in integrating R with Tableau and I am trying to duplicate the work of Bala Deshpande by showing the pearson correlation coefficient of the mtcars variables. The article of Deshpande is in this link. http://www.simafore.com/blog/bid/120209/Integrating-Tableau-and-R-for-data-analytics-in-four-simple-steps

I have already checked Rserve connection and it is in the processes. I have already checked my connection in Tableau and it said that it has successfully connected to R. The code I have written as a calculated field is written below.

SCRIPT_REAL("cor(.arg1,.arg2)",([Variable 1]),([Variable 2]))

But, when I try to put the correlation calculated field in the COLOR Marks, it shows a warning that states "An error occurred while communicating with the Rserve service" and when I click the SHOW DETAILS, it shows, "Error in cor(.arg1,.arg2): 'x' must be numeric"

I have seen some other posts and I did not see anything helpful. I have checked for any Null or missing values but there is none. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: Check the datatype of `Variable1` & `2` it should be numeric.

Comment: The correlation calculated field is now already working but I keep getting null result when I am putting it in the Color Marks. Any suggestions?

Comment: May be you should try computing the result along the `dimension`.

Comment: It is just the thing that was missing. Thanks for the help!